# CSS width 100% no working

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar that is set to width 100%. It displays perfectly but the problem is that when it is zoomed, a space is left in the right side. You can see the working example at http://jsfiddle.net/ShNtf/
The follwing is my CSS code:-

```
.nav-container{
    width:100%;
    color:#fff;
    background:#000;
}
.nav-contained{
    min-width:350px;
}
}
body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

Comment: Can't see any problem. Actually, I couldn't see a scroll bar anyway.

Comment: See this: http://jsfiddle.net/ShNtf/embedded/result/
The problems is just with minimal width on jsfiddle

Comment: does it make sense to add max-width: 100%; to the .nav-contained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

When a horizontal scroll-bar is visible, background color doesn't fill browser width.

**Solution:**

I had success by moving the `background-color` definition to from `.nav-container` to `.nav-contained`.

```
.nav-container {
    width:100%;
}
.nav-contained {
    min-width:350px;
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ShNtf/7/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to keep min-width, add it to the container and it will work:

```
.nav-container{
  width:100%;
  color:#fff;
  background-color:#000;
  min-width:350px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because of min-width. When you zoom in, 350px are "multiplied" and if it is more than outer container width, it becomes wider and scrollbar is shown.

Remove that min-width to make words break into multiple lines after zooming.

Comment: I don't think the issue is the scrolling. It's that the background color doesn't fill the width when there is a horizontal scrollbar ("a space is left in the right side.") The OP may want/need the `min-width`.